# Hibernate Reverse Engineering type-mapping of Number columns from a view

Tags: oracle, hibernate, view, reverse-engineering

So, I have a requirement when reverse-engineering an Oracle schema to do two things:

1. All Number oracle types that explicitly have a scale of 0 to revenge into a java.lang.Long
2. All other Number columns to reverse engineer into a java.math.BigDecimal

So, to solve problem #1, I have this entry in the hibernate.reveng.xml:

`<sql-type jdbc-type="DECIMAL" scale="0" hibernate-type="java.lang.Long" />`

This works just fine for any datatype like: `NUMBER(6,0)`  but in Oracle if you create a view that aggregates a number column with some scale, the data type in the view is just `NUMBER`

So a view like:

`create or replace view v_myview (myTotal)
AS
 select sum(cost) myTotal from sales`

The myTotal column will return as a `NUMBER` and be converted to a Long when reverse-engineering.

I don't know how to fix this.  Is there a type mapping that can be given that explicitly says to have NO precision?